# Assign case to the least occupied person in team

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I have a requirement to assign the cases based on the user's capacity in a specified group. There are 20 users in a team. I need to check the capacity of the user whose capacity is less than other, basically case will be assigned to the lest occupied person in the team.

BELOW IS THE STEPS WHICH WE TRIED:

1. Using workflow assign the case into a specific queue.
2. Schedule a batch job to query the cases in the queue and update the case owner and also user capacity in a custom object.
3. We need to assign the cases to the least occupied user. Since it is batch we can query the capacity of the user from user capacity object and stored the details in a map.
4. When first case is assigned to X user, his capacity needs to be consider when the second is going to assign.

I have a problem in updating capacity user in the user capacity every time. I would like to store it somewhere and compare the same while assign the cases and update all the capacities at last as a single DML.

Could anyone help me in framing the logic.

Comment: Are you planning to use Omni Channel?

Comment: Without looking at code, noone can help you out, would you mind sharing those relevant bits?

Comment: We planned to assign case owner using apex batch but in the logic, picking the least capacity user first time is working, but when second case comes in it couldn't consider the increased capacity of the first case owner since we are not updating the database every time.

Comment: You need to state your use cases. Is the case only created one at a time or can create in bulk? Logic to handle single and bulk are different...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing code, you could prefer to use Omni-Channel.

> Omni-Channel is a flexible, customizable feature, and you can configure it declaratively—that is, without writing code. Use Omni-Channel to manage the priority of work items, which makes it a cinch to route important work items to agents quickly. Manage your agents’ capacity to take on work items so that they’re given only the number of assignments that they can handle. You can also define which agents can work on different types of assignments. For example, you can create one group of agents to respond to leads and sales inquiries, and another group that helps customers with support questions.

Best of all, Omni-Channel routes all these assignments to the correct agents automatically. Agents no longer have to pick and choose work assignments manually from a queue, which saves everyone in your call center time, effort, and brainpower. Because it’s easier for agents to work on their assignments, they can assist your customers faster and more effectively and close assignments more quickly.

For more information, refer [Omni-Channel Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/service_omnichannel) Trailhead module.

Comment: The reason why we didn't prefer omni channel is that case will not be assigned to specific user until unless they themselves change the status into the presence status. Also through omni channel we cannot configure capacity for each user